# Can I generate images in Clojure and show them inline in LightTable REPL?

Tags: image, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, lighttable

I want to write some Clojure code which would manipulate images, and I wonder if there's a way to show them in the LightTable REPL inline?

Comment: FWIW I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/light-table-discussion/inline$20image/light-table-discussion/ZenslThX9kU/WUfS3QNBISsJ) post (from Sept. 2013) in the LT google group and it wasn't available at that time. I couldn't find any mention of a plan to implement it.

Comment: Although... LT is basically implemented with HTML and CSS so if you can either an `<img/>` tag somewhere with the path to the image or encode it in Base64 you are done :P .

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @juan.facorro it should be as easy as encoding a certain image with base64 information. This is definitely possible and it is already in use in the python plugin. They use it together with matplotlib and iPython to create inline plots which is really cool.

Sadly this is not (yet) implemented in lighttable's Clojure plugin. I have been discussing with the lighttable team to implement this. You can check it [here](https://github.com/LightTable/Clojure/issues/75#issuecomment-176293371). For the moment I don't have much time so if you want to contribute (either to the discussion or programming it yourself) you are much welcome